# azure virtual machine linux diagnostic agent unable to find its event hub

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm tasked by my company to integrate "azure audit logs" for some of important services e.g virtual machine and azure activity logs.

I'm new to whole azure technology, and i'm doing my best to get it done.

So,far I have setup , "virtual machine linux diagnostic agent" using

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/diagnostics-linux

The output in json is given in link here

https://jmp.sh/Xbs1SXg

My objective is to get those events read / process by "event hubs". In the JSON, i see now mention of "sinks" or "eventhub" entry. I don't know where this data is shipped.

for e.g

```
"sink": [
    {
        "name": "sinkname",
        "type": "EventHub",
        "sasURL": "https SAS URL"
    },
    ...
]
```

Where and how can i use this? because in my json i don't see this code block.

I have created, a event-hub workspace and instance, but I don't know how to connect the two.

I'm attaching some of errors, I'm getting on "export template tab".

[export template error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5z54.png)
[export template error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuiHS.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. How are the errors related to you question? Try to ask a specific question. Have also a look at the [ask] link.

Comment: Cross posted here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22534490-e30a-4f3e-b7c5-8f7d116a934f/azure-virtual-machine-linux-diagnostic-agent-unable-to-find-its-event-hub?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows